# Cordova (PhoneGap) reinitializing on every page of jQuery Mobile app

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I've been writing a simple four-screen Android application using Cordova and jQuery Mobile. The different screens are arranged inside a single page of HTML as DIVs with the data-role="page" attribute. I basically copied the multi-page sample template from the jQuery Mobile documentation.

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

Navigation between the pages happens via a persistent navbar stuck to the bottom of each page. Again, I used the code suggested in the jQuery Mobile docs with little modification.

```
<div data-role="footer" data-id="appNavBar" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#homePage" data-icon="home" data-transition="none" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#historyPage" data-icon="grid" data-transition="none">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="#settingsPage" data-icon="gear" data-transition="none">Settings</a></li>
            <li><a href="#aboutPage" data-icon="info" data-transition="none">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The various Javascript libraries are included in the head section of the HTML page, as follows (application.js contains the logic of the app).

```
<head> 
    <title>Redacted</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/RedactedTheme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="application.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="flot/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.7.0.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="statusbarnotification.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="application.js"></script>
</head>
```

When Cordova is finished loading and is ready for use, it emits the "deviceready" signal. the Cordova docs recommend binding all setup code to an event listener tied to that signal. I have done it like this in application.js:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.debug("Cordova initialized.");
    setup();
}
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady);
```

setup() is a function that reads information from the browser Web SQL database and storage (using the Cordova API defined [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)) in order to maintain user preferences and usage information between application launches.

Now for the problem: I was under the impression that jQuery Mobile would use the jQuery ajax method to load any subsequent pages after the first page, and that in doing so it would strip out the head section and skip straight to the DIV with the data-role="page" attribute and the appropriate ID. What I am observing instead is that the scripts in the head section appear to be reloaded whenever I visit a new page of the application. This happens the first time the page is visited in the session and then stops happening.

It appears that Cordova is being reinitialized and that it is emitting the deviceready signal again. Using LogCat in Eclipse, I can see the debug message I placed in the onDeviceReady function. the setup() function is also being called again. This slows things down considerably.

Does anybody know where I'm going wrong? Is there a way to ensure that Cordova only loads once?

Thanks,
Evan

Comment: check out handlebars (http://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/handlebars-templates.html) and pageslider (https://github.com/ccoenraets/PageSlider)

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem using the phonegap facebook connect plugin. The only workaround is to design the entire app to be one html document with panels that are shown and hidden as your different screens. If you want to keep the panels in separate files, you could use something like require.js

Answer (score 1):

I know that this issue is about 9 months old, but just in case my solution helps someone else with the same issue

Don't build your pages with display per HTML, instead build one long HTML page with each display part in it's own DIV with `data-role="page"`

Now, when you're changing page, you can use JQM's call of `$.mobile.changePage()` to change the display page

e.g. your page could look like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="startingPage">
<p onClick="$.mobile.changePage('page2')">Page Link</p>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
<p>more content here</p>
</div>
```

I know this seems counter-intuitive for most web development, but working with PhoneGap & JQM means **NOT** working in standard web development