# Can I listen for deviceready multiple time on Cordova 2.5?

Tags: javascript, cordova

Could I register 'deviceready' event for each html page? I use the initialize codes of Cordova 2.5 and it work fine. When I copy these codes to a new html file, It always call to the initialize() function of the index.html.

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        console.log('Received Event: XXX ' + id);

    }
};
```

===============
HTML file:

....

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                app.initialize();
                </script>
```

....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Device ready will fire only once. It will fire next time only when the app is killed and opened again.

Comment: ... or if you go to another page within the phone application you need to wait for the deviceready event again, right? (assuming you aren't using a single-page architecture).

Comment: DeviceReady is a PhoneGap event. PhoneGap doesnt care if the application is SPA or not. DeviceReady is fired when the app runs first time to signal that the device is ready to run the apps custom code.

Comment: Well, according to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782211/cordova-phonegap-reinitializing-on-every-page-of-jquery-mobile-app), and what i'm observing, it is firing whenever i move to a different hrml page..? Can you add a bit of explanation?

Comment: @TilwinJoy - Here we need to separate PhoneGap and your HTML5 based mobile app. Both have different life cycles. PhoneGap can be considered as a JVM or .NET run time while HTML5 is your source code. PhoneGap fires the deviceready event only once in its life cycle. Thats when all the PhoneGap APIs are ready to be called. Now you can kick start your HTML5 App and do anything you want with your app. If you kill your app and opens it againl, device ready will fire again to signal that its APIs are ready to be used.

Comment: Yes, but the thing is `any event handler registered after the event has been fired will have its callback function called immediately`. So if i move to another page say, by clicking an anchor: `onload` of which i'm binding `device ready` - then it'll fire (*not exactly- but the handler being invoked has kind of the same effect in practical*) So it'd be great if you updated your answer to avoid the confusion...