# Phonegap redirect in ios

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I have two pages: `page1` and `page2`

I have problem making the `deviceready` event to fire up again when I go back to `page 1`.

I have this code in `page1.html`:

```
//Works at first
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReadyPopup, false);
function onDeviceReadyPopup(){
    window.location.href="page2.html";
}
```

In page2.html, I have this code:

```
window.location.href="page1.html";
```

Problem: When I go back to `page1.html`, `deviceready` no longer executed.

Comment: I think deviceready fires only once. 
See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629278/can-i-listen-for-deviceready-multiple-time-on-cordova-2-5

Comment: @TineUršič But I need to execute again some codes inside `onDeviceReadyPopup` function.

Comment: Did u find solution for same question??

Comment: @DimpleDesai This is an old thread of mine. I don't think I have a solution on this scenario but as far as I remember, I switched to using some library / framework like ionic or framework7 that will support single page architecture. In this way, we no longer worry in a scenario like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can fire the deviceReady event in the page load of the HTML page .. Something like this

```
<html>
<body onLoad = "load()">
</body>
</html>
```

In the javascript

```
function load()
{
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReadyForAppVersion, false);
}
```

This way device ready event will be registered every time the page loads.

Hope this helps.